# How to create rounded rectangle ListView (ListActivity) in android?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, rounded-corners, shapes

Currently iam working in android application, Using ListActivity to create ListView, i give three items in ListView and setBackground image for Rounded rect in ListView, then run the app each corner has rounded rect showing fine, but rounded rect show in full screen, i want rounded rect until item 3. How to fix this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

ListView class:

```
public class Settings extends ListActivity
{
     private static String[] mListContent={"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set listview rounded rect
            getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
            getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_shape);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListContent));
            }
}
```

Custom_shape.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <padding android:left="14dp" android:top="14dp"
            android:right="14dp" android:bottom="14dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Below i have attached image for your reference:

i want to show the border line (ListView) end of the item 3. // its similarly grouped tableview in iPhone

[image]

I want to show like this:

[image]

Comment: post xml file containing listView

Comment: Using ListActivity to create listView inside the ListView class.

Answer (score -1):

ListView height pass in XML as wrap content instead od fill parent...

Comment: Can u please explain ellaborately